# Calcular días por estado en tabla SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Tengo la siguiente tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito calcular la cantidad de días por caso, ejemplo:
Caso A Ingresado: 1 día, Caso A Tramitado 5 días. ¿ Qué me pueden sugerir ?

Comment: Bienvenido Luis Valenzuela a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Puesto que estás tratando de obtener la diferencia entre filas aunque no haya cambio de estado, lo ideal es que uses la función `LAG()`. Esta te ayuda a traer el valor anterior (según los lineamientos que definas) para poder usarlo en la fila actual.

```
--Esto es para generar datos de prueba, no forma parte de la solución.
CREATE TABLE Casos(
    Num     int,
    Fecha   date,
    Caso    varchar(10),
    Estado  varchar(10),
    Dias    int)

INSERT INTO Casos( Num, Fecha, Caso, Estado)
VALUES( 1, '20200101', 'A', 'Ingresado'),
      ( 2, '20200101', 'A', 'Ingresado'),
      ( 3, '20200105', 'A', 'Tramitado'),
      ( 4, '20200110', 'A', 'Terminado'),
      ( 5, '20200101', 'B', 'Ingresado'),
      ( 6, '20200105', 'B', 'Tramitado'),
      ( 7, '20200107', 'B', 'Tramitado');

--Aquí inicia la solución
--Usamos un CTE como vista actualizable para poder usar la función LAG()
--No lo usamos directamente en el UPDATE, porque no lo permite la sintaxis.
WITH cteCasos AS(
    SELECT *, 
        DATEDIFF( DD, LAG( Fecha) OVER( PARTITION BY Caso ORDER BY Fecha), Fecha) + 1 AS DiasCalculados
    FROM Casos
)
UPDATE cteCasos SET
    Dias = DiasCalculados    
FROM cteCasos
--Agregamos un WHERE para reducir el trabajo realizado
WHERE DiasCalculados IS NOT NULL
  AND Dias IS NULL;

--Verificamos los datos
SELECT *
FROM Casos;
```